# Turn.js library and load function for each page

Tags: jquery, jquery-tooltip, yepnope, turnjs

I'm using the TurnJS library to make a flip book and I also using a tooltip library.

The book and the tooltips work for few pages but sometimes it not works. It seems that the tooltip function cannot be loaded. I don't know why. Do I have to use a specific event to solve this problem ?
Here is my tooltip function :

```
   $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.source').each(function() {
        var selector = '#' + $(this).data('source-id');
        Tipped.create(this, $(selector)[0], {
            skin: 'white',
            hook: 'topleft',
            hideOn: 'click',
            showOn: 'click',
            maxWidth: 250,
            closeButton: true

        });
    });
});
```

I load my flipbook like that:

```
  function loadApp() {    
     // Create the flipbook
      $('.flipbook').turn({
          // Width
          width: 900,
          // Height
          height: 620,
          // Elevation
          elevation: 50,
          // Enable gradients
          gradients: true,
          duration: 1000,
          pages: 16,
          // Auto center this flipbook
          autoCenter: true,   
      });  
  }   
   // Load the HTML4 version if there's not CSS transform

  yepnope({
      test: Modernizr.csstransforms,
      yep: ['lib/turn.js'],
      nope: ['lib/turn.html4.min.js'],
      both: ['css/basic.css'],
      complete: loadApp
  });
```

thanks for your help